# Getting list item in SharePoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I have used the below javascript code..

**.js File**

```
  'use strict';
var hostweburl;
var appweburl;

$(document).ready(function () {

    hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(
getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    appweburl = decodeURIComponent(
getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));

    var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", loadPage);
});

function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve) return singleParam[1];
    }
}
function loadPage() {
    getListItems();
}
function getListItems() {
    var executor;

    executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync({
        url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('EmpInfoList')/items?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
             method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: getListItemsSuccessHandler,
        error: getListItemsErrorHandler
    });
}
function getListItemsSuccessHandler(data) {

    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
    var selectListItems = document.getElementById("selectListItems");
    var results = jsonObject.d.results;

    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var selectOption = document.createElement("option");
        selectOption.value = results[i].EmpInfoList;
        selectOption.innerText = results[i].EmpInfoList;
        selectListItems.appendChild(selectOption);
    }
}
function getListItemsErrorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
    alert("Could not get list items: " + errorMessage);
}
```

**Default.aspx**

```
<%-- The following 4 lines are ASP.NET directives needed when using SharePoint components --%>

<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Language="VB" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <head> of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
    <WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add your CSS styles to the following file -->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/App.css" />
   <%-- <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/style.css" />--%>

    <!-- Add your JavaScript to the following file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/App.js"></script>
</asp:Content>

<%-- The markup in the following Content element will be placed in the TitleArea of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
   Employee Details
</asp:Content>

<%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <body> of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">



     <div>
<p>
<b>List Items</b>
<br />
<select style="height:300px; width:310px" multiple="multiple" id="selectListItems"></select>
</p>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

It is not able to get the list item, instead it shows undefined..

Comment: Where is the design page code. What is the data type of the field from which you are retrieving the values?

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint hosted app, You need not use `SP.RequestExecutor`. Just make a direct Ajax call like following

```
$.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('EmpInfoList')/items",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all the `getQueryStringParameter` stuff with just 3 lines:

```
JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
var hostweburl = JSRequest.QueryString['SPHostUrl'];
var appweburl  = JSRequest.QueryString['SPAppWebUrl'];
```

The examples on those Microsoft sites were written by someone who does not know what native SharePoint code is available.